# How can I convert json with uppercased field names to object?

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have json

```
{
    "Person": {
        "PersonId": 122,
        "Name": "John",
        "Surname": "Doe",
        "age": 2
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to Java class

```
    public class Person {
        private String personId;
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private int age;
        
        //getters,setters...
    }
```

What I already have tried is

```
    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new LowerCaseStrategy());
        return mapper;
    }

    public static class LowerCaseStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase {
        @Override
        public String translate(String input) {
            char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
            chars[0] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[0]);
            return new String(chars);
        }
    }
```

But it did not help.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be solved?

upd: I don't have permission to change `Person` class.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The one error you made, is the direction in which the PropertyNamingStrategy applies: You are converting *from* Java name, *to* JSON name, not the other way around. So, this should work:

```
        @Override
        public String translate(String input) {
            char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
            chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]); // upper!
            return new String(chars);
        }
```

Also, Jackson has `PropertyNamingStrategies.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` which should do the thing you need without implementing your own.

Answer (score -2):

To convert the JSON with uppercased field names to the desired Java class, you can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation from Jackson library. Here's how you can modify your `Person` class and ObjectMapper configuration to achieve the conversion:

1. Modify the `Person` class to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```java
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("PersonId")
    private String personId;
    
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("Surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private int age;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

2. Remove the custom `LowerCaseStrategy` from your ObjectMapper configuration since the field names in your JSON are already in lowercase.

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Now, when you deserialize the JSON using the updated ObjectMapper, it will correctly map the fields with uppercased names to the corresponding fields in the `Person` class.

For example:

```java
String jsonString = "{\"Person\":{\"PersonId\":122,\"Name\":\"John\",\"Surname\":\"Doe\",\"age\":2}}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);

System.out.println(person.getPersonId()); // Output: 122
System.out.println(person.getName()); // Output: John
System.out.println(person.getSurname()); // Output: Doe
System.out.println(person.getAge()); // Output: 2
```

With these changes, the JSON with uppercased field names will be correctly converted to the Java `Person` object.

Comment: But I don't have permission to change `Person` class.

Comment: If you don't have permission to modify the `Person` class, you can use a custom deserializer to achieve the desired conversion from the JSON with uppercased field names to the existing `Person` class.

Here's how you can implement a custom deserializer using Jackson: